# How to get specific files using Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I am trying to get all files with today's date in the file name. However, when I run this, I get the following error:

```
#Share location
$source = "U:\Data\*"
#Sharepoint file location
$prefix = "file_name_"

#Date Info
$date = get-date -uformat "%Y-%m-%d" | Out-String

$file = $prefix + $date 

Get-ChildItem -File -path $source -Filter $file*
```

> Get-ChildItem : Illegal characters in path. At line:2 char:1
>   + Get-ChildItem -File -path $source -Filter $file*

Any help would be appreciated. I am using `$file*` in the filter because the file extension could be different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your **problem is the use of `| Out-String`** which is not only unnecessary in your case, but **appends a trailing newline**, which is the cause of the problem.

Use just:

```
$date = get-date -uformat "%Y-%m-%d"  # Do NOT use ... | Out-String
```

`get-date -uformat "%Y-%m-%d"` directly returns a `[string]`.

---

**Optional troubleshooting tips**:

To verify that `get-date -uformat "%Y-%m-%d"` outputs a `[string]` instance:

```
PS> (get-date -uformat "%Y-%m-%d").GetType().FullName
System.String
```

To verify that `... | Out-String` appends a newline:

```
PS> (get-date -uformat "%Y-%m-%d" | Out-String).EndsWith("`n")
True
```

Comment: @ZackV could you update the question with a sample file name?

Comment: My code now works using "$file*" instead of $file* (including the previous suggestions). Thank you!

Comment: @ZackV: Glad to hear it, but that's curious: while `"$file*"` is the _generally preferable_ form, `$file*` should work _the same_ in this case. Are you sure that the `"..."` made the difference? Can you paste the expanded value of `$file` here, so I can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
#Share location
 $source = "U:\Data\*"
#Sharepoint file location
 $prefix = "file_name_"

#Date Info
 $date = get-date -uformat "%Y-%m-%d" | Out-String

 $file = $prefix + $date + ".*"

 $webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
 $webclient.UseDefaultCredentials = $true 

 Get-ChildItem -File -path $source -Filter $file
```

The way you currently have it, PowerShell is trying to pass a variable called `$file*` to `Get-ChildItem`.

Comment: That runs successfully however no file is found. I assume that is because I am not explicitly listing the file extension in the $file variable. Is there not a way to wildcard this? to grab any item that counts the text found in $file

Comment: Remove `.` from `.*` - wildcard globbing is not regex

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen's is correct; also, `$file*` works fine as an argument (though `"$file*"` is arguably preferable), so that can't be the problem; try `$file = 'foo'; Write-Output $file*`

Comment: My code now works using "$file*" instead of $file* (including the previous suggestions). Thank you!